# SwiftUI - TabView item recreation

Tags: swiftui, tabview

Is it possible to recreate tabview item when you click on it.
For example if I am on tabitem1, then click tabitem2, then go back to tabitem1, I want tabitem1 to be recreated. Can I do that in SwiftUI?

Comment: Would you provided more details of what do you try to achieve with some code to demo?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example how to reload all Views when changing the active TabBar Item. You use selection parameter in TabView and then use that selection inside your ContentView to make it reload whenever the selection changes.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selection = 0
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            DefaultView(string: "First")
                .tag(0)
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "list.dash")
                    Text("Menu")
                }
                .id(UUID())

            DefaultView(string: "Second")
                .tag(1)
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
                    Text("Order")
                }
        }
        .id(selection == 0 ? UUID() : UUID()) //<< here is selection used to make the view reload 
    }
}
```

If you check `init()` method on DefaultView(), you will see it's getting called on every selection change.

Comment: Great answer davidev, that saved my live! What I don't clearly understand is the purpose of .id(selection == 0 ? UUID() : UUID()). Wouldn't it be cleaner to say .id(UUID()) ?